# Move Functions from Where Clause to Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a union query that runs abysmally slow I believe mostly because there are two functions in the where clause of each union.  I am pretty sure that there is no getting around the unions, but there may be a way to move the functions from the where of each.  I won't post ALL of the union sections because I don't think it is necessary as they are all almost identical with the exception of one table in each.  The first function was created by someone else but it takes a date, and uses the "frequency" value like "years, months, days, etc." and the "interval" value like 3, 4, 90 to calculate the new "Due Date".  For instance, a date of today with a frequency of years, and an interval of 3, would produce the date 4/21/2025.  Here is the actual function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ReturnExpiration_IntervalxFreq](@Date datetime2,@int int, @freq int)  
RETURNS datetime2   
AS     
BEGIN  
    declare @d datetime2;
    SELECT @d = case when @int = 1 then null-- '12-31-9999' 
                     when @int = 2 then dateadd(day,@freq,@date) 
                     when @int = 3 then dateadd(week,@freq,@date) 
                     when @int = 4 then dateadd(month,@freq,@date) 
                     when @int = 5 then dateadd(quarter,@freq,@date) 
                     when @int = 6 then dateadd(year,@freq,@date) 
                end
    RETURN @d;
```

The query itself is supposed to find and identify records whose Due Date has past or is within 90 days of the current date.  Here is what each section of the union looks like

```
SELECT
    R.RequirementId
    , EC.EmployeeCompanyId
    , EC.CompanyId
    , DaysOverdue = 
        CASE WHEN 
            R.DueDate IS NULL
        THEN 
            CASE WHEN 
                 EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_Training_Requirement_Compliance RC WHERE RC.EmployeeCompanyId = EC.EmployeeCompanyId AND RC.RequirementId = R.RequirementId AND RC.Active = 1 AND ((DATEDIFF(DAY, R.DueDate, GETDATE()) > -91 OR R.DueDate Is Null ) OR (DATEDIFF(DAY, dbo.ReturnExpiration_IntervalxFreq(TRC.EffectiveDate, R.IntervalId, R.Frequency), GETDATE()) > -91)) OR R.IntervalId IS NULL)
            THEN 
                DateDiff(day,ISNULL(dbo.ReturnExpiration_IntervalxFreq(TRC.EffectiveDate, R.IntervalId, R.Frequency), '12/31/9999'),getdate())
            ELSE 
            0
            END
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(day,R.DueDate,getdate()) 
        END 
        ,CASE WHEN 
                EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_Training_Requirement_Compliance RC WHERE RC.EmployeeCompanyId = EC.EmployeeCompanyId AND RC.RequirementId = R.RequirementId AND RC.Active=1 AND (GETDATE() > dbo.ReturnExpiration_IntervalxFreq(RC.EffectiveDate, R.IntervalId, R.Frequency) OR R.IntervalId IS NULL))
            THEN 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),dbo.ReturnExpiration_IntervalxFreq(TRC.EffectiveDate, R.IntervalId, R.Frequency), 101)
            ELSE 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),R.DueDate,101)
            END As DateDue
FROM
    @Employees AS EC
    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Training_Requirement_To_Position TRP ON TRP.PositionId = EC.PositionId
    INNER JOIN @CompanyReqs R ON R.RequirementId = TRP.RequirementId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Training_Requirement_Compliance TRC ON TRC.EmployeeCompanyId = EC.EmployeeCompanyId AND TRC.RequirementId = R.RequirementId AND TRC.Active = 1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
        FROM tbl_Training_Requirement_Compliance RC
        WHERE RC.EmployeeCompanyId = EC.EmployeeCompanyId
        AND RC.RequirementId = R.RequirementId
        AND RC.Active = 1
    )
    OR (
        (DATEDIFF(DAY, R.DueDate, GETDATE()) > -91
      OR R.DueDate Is Null )
      OR (DATEDIFF(DAY, dbo.ReturnExpiration_IntervalxFreq(TRC.EffectiveDate, R.IntervalId, R.Frequency), GETDATE()) > -91))

UNION...
```

It is supposed to exclude records that either don't exist at all on the tbl_Training_Requirement_Compliance table, or if they do exist, once the frequency an intervals have been calculated, would have a new due date that is within 90 days of the current date.  I am hoping that someone with much more experience and expertise in SQL Server can show me a way, if possible, to remove the functions from the WHERE clause and help the performance of this stored procedure.

Comment: Your query isn't SARGable; you have functions on columns in the `WHERE`, such as `DATEDIFF(DAY, R.DueDate, GETDATE())`. `UNION` is also a very expensive operator; are you sure you need `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using too? Is it 2019? if not, you would likely find much better performance with a inline table value function over a (multi-line) scalar function.

Comment: SQL version is 2019.  @Larnu - I believe I can't get around the union, but if you think it is possible, I can post the entire thing.  The Union is because there several junction tables Requirement_To_Department, Requireqment_To_Position.  I will post it all, and if you see a way around the unions, by all means let me know.

Comment: My question wasn't can get "around" the `UNION`, it was do you *need* to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`?

Comment: For performance issues, we need to see tables and indexes, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Technically, there shouldn't be duplicates so, perhaps, I could try UNION ALL.

Comment: To make those queries sarge-able you need to change things like `(DATEDIFF(DAY, R.DueDate, GETDATE()) > -91` to `R.DueDate > DATEADD(DAY, -91, GETDATE())` and somehow get rid of those `OR` conditions

Comment: @Charlieface.  I was able include the execution plan (this is my first time), but I can't figure out how to copy/paste it without taking screenshot.  I also tried retrieving and pasting the XML in the link you sent but I receive "The supplied XML did not parse correctly. Are you sure you have a valid query plan XML text?"

Comment: Use Paste the Plan, as Charlieface stated, @RaniRadcliff . It has [instructions](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/), so follow those.

Comment: `UNION ALL` will be much "cheaper" than `UNION`; it won't force the data engine to sort your dataset(s) and then remove any duplicate rows. As you state there aren't any duplicates the sorting is just an expensive waste of resources.

Comment: I followed the instructions to paste the xml but it won't submit.  I tried including the first line that starts "?xml", I tried not including it.  I tried starting from the BatchSequence tag.  It won't paste.'

Comment: You need to make sure the first character is `<` sometimes there is an extra space. Or paste it into your question above and we can see what can be done. We must have the plan, this question is not answerable otherwise

Comment: It doesn't seem to have an extra space.  I pasted it, put my cursor in front of the < and hit the back button.  I wish there was a way to attach a file here.

Comment: Just paste it in above as a code block, we can sort it out

Comment: *"I wish there was a way to attach a file here."* I don't... There should never be a reason to do so.

Comment: @Charlieface I tried including Execution Plan as a code block but it is too large, so it won't let me paste it.  I tried pasting an execution plan from a simple select statement into that site, and that won't paste either, so I'm not sure what the issue is.  I sent an email requesting help from the site admin/owner If I am able to get it pasted, I will include the link here.  Thanks all for trying to help.

Comment: @Larnu I wouldn't say that, this is one example, I have seen this issue with PasteThePlan before. Try PasteBin maybe?

Comment: I really don't want to see people uploading zip files of their database, @Charlieface . (It's bad enough when they do it via a 3rd party source.)

Comment: @Charlieface - I signed up for pastebin and received "You have exceeded the maximum paste size of 512 kilobytes per paste".  I tried to pay for a Pro account but it says they are sold out.  I will continue to try PastePlan off and on.  Thanks again for the help and your time.